# How to create and scan a list/array ... in embedded CLIPS

Tags: c++, database, clips

How can I create complex data structures in CLIPS? 
I will shortly explain what I intend to do:

if I have a list in C++ for example a list of car models. 
several users then input keywords, I want to trigger an alert each time a keyword is not in the car models list.

I don't want to create a rule for each car model.

Answer (score 0):

Use COOL instances. These are the closest analog to C++ classes.